# Implementation of Babai's GI algorithm

Tags: graph-isomorphism

Babai proved that there is a quasi-polynomial-time algorithm for graph isomorphism. Has anyone implemented this algorithm? I think the code will be easier to understand than his paper, because of the amount of abstract algebra one needs to master beforehand. Of course one may need to learn that after reading the code. But has it been implemented?

Comment: I doubt anyone will bother implementing it.

Comment: Well, Section 12 actually contains a piece of high-level pseudo-code, which serves my purpose to some extent. Didn't notice it before.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus why do you think that? Wouldn't a guaranteed quasi-polynomial-time GI solution be of interest to implement?

Comment: @HansBrende There are more practical algorithms which work well on most instances. Babai’s algorithm is probably impractical.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus what about his paper indicates that his algorithm would be "probably impractical"? Have you read his paper or is that a guess?

Comment: @HansBrende The paper is quite long, and the algorithm is quite complex. Have you taken a look?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I have not... hence why I was hoping someone else has done so and has something better than a guess. But complexity ≠ impracticality. (I also don't understand the complexity of the Nauty paper at first glance but that one has a quite efficient implementation).

Comment: I urge you to take a look.